# React Router 4 + Code splitting | Component remounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, code-splitting, react-loadable

I have the next code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Loadable from 'react-loadable'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        kappa: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setState({ kappa: true })
        }, 1000)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <Route exact path="/:locale/" component={Loadable({
                    loader: () => import('../views/IndexPage/index.jsx'),
                    loading: () => "loading"
                })} />
                <Route exact path="/:locale/registration" component={Loadable({
                    loader: () => import('../views/Registration/index.jsx'),
                    loading: () => "loading"
                })} />

                {this.state.kappa && <p>Hey, Kappa-Kappa, hey, Kappa-Kappa, hey!</p>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When state updates (`kappa` becomes true and `p` appears), component on active route (no matter what is it - `IndexPage` or `Registration`) remounts. If I import component manually in App and pass it to the `Route` without code-splitting, components on routes doesn't remount (that's so obvious).

I also tried webpack's dynamic import, like this:

```
<Route path="/some-path" component={props => <AsyncView {...props} component="ComponentFolderName" />
```

where `` import(`/path/to/${this.props.component}/index.jsx`) `` runs in `componentDidMount` and upfills `AsyncView`'s state, and it behaves simillar to `Loadable` situation.

I suppose, the problem is that `component` for `Route` is an anonymous function

The question is: how to avoid remount of route components?

Comment: Found a little workaround - pass to `Route` some static component (e. g. `AsyncRoute`) and then define an array of routes with component names and try to import with `webpack`'s dynamic `import`. Quite bad solution in sense of no dynamics, but it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this behaviour is normal and documented at React Router 4 docs:

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render. This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the children prop (below).

`render` works fine both with React Loader and webpack's code splitting.

Comment: In new React router render prop is not present so what can we use in that case
i am using react-router 6.2.1